# ldd says "not found" for one file, and found for another

Tags: linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to gather all the dependencies needed by some `.so` file. I use the [Recursive ldd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/recursive-ldd/files/) script, but that doesn't really matter for the manner of sake.

I want to put all the .so files in one directory, say it's in

```
/home/user/project/lib
```

I'm having a weird experience: Say there's a file `libmat.so` which I want to gather all its dependencies. So I ran

```
/home/user/project/lib$ ldd libmat.so
...
 libmwboost_system.so.1.65.1 => /home/user/project/lib/libmwboost_system.so.1.65.1
 libmwboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1 => /home/user/project/lib/libmwboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1
 ...
```

So we see that `ldd` recognized the `libmwboost_system.so.1.65.1` file in the current directory. 
Turns out that `libmwboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1.so` also depends on `libmwboost_system.so.1.65.1`,
But when I run:

```
/home/user/project/lib$ ldd libmwboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1
...
 libmwboost_system.so.1.65.1 => not found
 ...
```

How come `ldd` can find it when I run in on `libmat.so` and can't when I run it on `libmwboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1` ?

I would be glad if someone could provide an explanation in the context of the linking process. As far as I know, when you link a file against a library, you use the following flags:

```
~$ gcc my_program.c -Lpath/to/solib/for/static/linker -lnameoflib -wl,-rpath=path/to/solib/for/dynamic/linker
```

This `-Wl,-rpath` flag embeds in the executable the path of the library that the dynamic linker will search for at run time. In the case of a shared library that depends on other libraries - does it work the same?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so that's how it works:

When linking a binary - whether it's an executable or another shared library - against a shared library, the static linker embeds in the binary the names of the libraries we linked against. Those libraries will be loaded by the dynmaic linker - `ld.so` -  once the program is run by the user.

Now the question is where the dynamic linker will search for these libraries at runtime. Briefly, according to the man page of `ld.so`, when the dynamic linker first inspects the binary to resolve its dependencies, it goes through the strings of the dependencies. If a string contains a slash "/" then the string is interpreted as a path. This can happen if the library name was specified with a slash at link time, like this:

```
~$ gcc prog.c ../path/to/library.so
```

In this case, the string embeded in the executable will be: `../path/to/library.so` and the dynamic linker will search it relatively to the location of the binary.

If not, it will search for the library in a list of locations (the whole list is specified in the man page). The first location is the directories specified in the DT_RUNPATH section attribute of the binary. This can be set at link time using the `-Wl,-rpath` flag:

```
~$ gcc prog.c -Lpath/of/lib/ -lmylib -Wl,-rpath=path/of/lib
```

In this case, the `path/of/lib` will be searched for the library by the dynamic library.

You can inspect this attribute using readelf:

```
~$ readelf -d binary | grep RUNPATH
```

In my case, the `libmat.so` library contained a RUNPATH attribute set to `$ORIGIN`, meaning that libraries will be searched in the same location of the binary library. Whereas, the `libmwboost_filesystem.so.1.65.1` didn't have this attribute set, that is why `ldd` didn't find the library.

`ldd` is just using `ld.so` to try and load the libraries, and shows where it found them, according to the search path specified in the `ld.so` man page.